# Star layout using Cystoscape JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use Cystoscape (http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/) to create a star layout. I am able to get all the nodes and relate them accordingly. What i am unable to do is to make the central node appear in the center while the others appearing in a constellation fashion.

[image: Star Layout]

```
        $('#cy').cytoscape({
        elements: [
            { // node n1
            group: 'nodes', // 'nodes' for a node, 'edges' for an edge
        data: { // element data (put dev data here)
            id: 'n1', // mandatory for each element, assigned automatically on undefined
            parent: 'nparent', // indicates the compound node parent id; not defined => no parent
            },

            position: { // the model position of the node (optional on init, mandatory after)
            x: 100,
            y: 100
            },

            selected: false, // whether the element is selected (default false)
            selectable: true, // whether the selection state is mutable (default true)
            locked: false, // when locked a node's position is immutable (default false)

            grabbable: true, // whether the node can be grabbed and moved by the user

            classes: 'foo bar' // a space separated list of class names that the element has
            },

         { // node n2
            group: 'nodes',
            data: { id: 'n2' },
            renderedPosition: { x: 200, y: 200 } // can alternatively specify position in rendered on-screen pixels
            },

            { // node n3
            group: 'nodes',
            data: { id: 'n3', parent: 'nparent' },
            position: { x: 123, y: 234 }
            },

            { // node nparent
            group: 'nodes',
            data: { id: 'nparent' }
            },

            { // edge e1
            group: 'edges',
            data: {
                id: 'e1',
            source: 'n1', // the source node id (edge comes from this node)
                target: 'n2'  // the target node id (edge goes to this node)
            }
            }
        ],

        // so we can see the ids
        style: cytoscape.stylesheet().
            selector('node')
            .css({
             'content': 'data(id)'
             })

        });
```

Additional problem i am facing is the ability to add a new node. Being new to this library, i would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the link http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/#style/properties
and change the node property "shape" to "star" as follows. It will automatically change your topology to star shape. Then you will not need to specify positions x,y of each node. And it will automatically appear in center

> shape:star